# Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value when creating a file in android

Tags: java, android

This error occurs every time i try to write a file with any of the available libraries such as opencsv or itext etc . Please tell me how to resolve it. Sometimes removing bootstrap entries work but i need to be able to make it work in an android application project

Comment: what is your code, where does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

What about this? (just pulled it from my own file creation in my Android app)

```
 /**
 * Creates a new file in the directory
 * @param sFilePath
 * @param sFileName
 */
public static void CreateFile(String sFilePath, String sFileName)
{
    try
    {
        File fileDir = new File(sFilePath);
        fileDir.mkdirs();
        File f = new File(fileDir, sFileName); // if the file already exists it will be overwritten
        f.createNewFile();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```